# How to Set GPO to Update Compatibility View List in IE9

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer-9

We recently started upgrading people in our organization to IE 9. One of the websites that our employees will be going to on a daily basis does not display the scroll bars correctly in IE 9. It does however display them correctly when the site is added to the compatibility view list in IE 9.

How can I set this through a group policy? Has this option been released yet?

In `Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Compatibility View` I only see options for IE7. Also in `Preferences\Control Panel\Internet Settings` it is only letting me create new group policy settings for IE 5-8.

The DC is running on W2K8R2 and is fully up to date.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, using the group policy for IE7 seemed to pass on fine to IE9. It seems that I should have tried it out with IE7 settings instead of getting scared away by the fact it said IE7 instead of IE9.

What it's saying about being IE7 is that it's a list of "IE7 Compatible" sites which is just another way to say Compatibility Mode sites. Just

[image: GP Screen Shot]

Comment: Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 2):

From a Google search (which you should have done before posting your question) it appears that if you install IE9 on the computer where you have the GPMC installed (presumably your domain controllers) that the inetres.admx template will be updated with the IE9 settings.